# Custom error page for SharePoint 2013 runtime error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I have found many links regarding custom error pages. But all the links are pointing to the same issue like `PageNotFoundError` which is not my case.

I need to create a custom error page for whenever any runtime error occurs in Sharepoint, for example:

> Runtime Error
>           Server Error in '/' Application
>           Runtime Error
>           Description:... .."

Instead of above error, I want to show a proper error page which says something like

> Contact Administrator etc..."

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer, but I have a suggestion. Customize `Error.aspx` page which is located at 15 hive layouts folder. But before doing that, take a backup of the file.

Add script block at the end in PlaceHolderMain. If you identify a message which contains the Runtime error, redirect to your custom page.